# Attempting to have an object move in the direction user swipes the screen: Corona SDK

Tags: game-physics, coronasdk

I've just started with a basic Corona SDK project, and I have hit a bit of a roadblock. I have made objects and menus fine, and even added gravity to the game, but I was wondering if there was a simple method to have an object move when the user swiped the screen, and the object would move in that general direction.

Any help would be much appreciated, the code for my object is down below

```
    -- make a Chameleon 
local Chameleon = display.newImageRect( "Chameleon.png", 70, 70 )
Chameleon.x= 50
Chameleon.y= 440
    physics.addBody(Chameleon, "dynamic", {density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=12})

function touchScreen(event)
  -- print("touch")
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can refer to the below code if you want to achieve draggable object with linear velocity just copy the code and make new project

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

local Rect = display.newRect(30,30,30,30)
Rect:setFillColor(255,0,0)

local flooring = display.newRect(0,display.contentHeight/1.1, display.contentWidth, 10)
    physics.addBody(Rect,"dynamic")
    physics.addBody(flooring,"static")

    local activateDash = false
    local bx = 0
    local by = 0

    heroTouch = function(event)
        if Rect then
            if event.phase == "began" then
                bx = event.x
                by = event.y
            elseif event.phase == "moved" then
                activateDash = true
            elseif event.phase == "ended" then
                if activateDash then
                    if _G.gX == 0 and _G.gY ~= 0 then
                        Rect:setLinearVelocity(event.x-bx,0)
                    elseif _G.gX ~= 0 and _G.gY == 0 then
                        Rect:setLinearVelocity(0,event.y-by)
                    else
                        Rect:setLinearVelocity(event.x-bx,event.y-by)
                    end
                    activateDash = false
                end
            end
        end
    end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch",heroTouch)
```

hope this can help

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great! While I still have you, if you don't mind, If I want to make the object stop and hang on a certain point (after being flung on to the point), could you direct me to what method that may be, or another example.

Comment: how exactly do you want the object stop on specific position if it collide with another object or if it goes to a certain point?. btw you can vote up the answer to make it a reference to others

Comment: If it were to go on a certain point. And I would vote it up, but I don't have enough reputation points. Only 3 sadly.

Comment: you can detect the x and y axis of Rect and when it goes to a certain point that you want it to stop make the physics body of Rect static

Comment: you can also remove the physics body if you want to make it stop falling